# Postman saying "The route api...could not be found." (laravel)

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I am trying to withdraw a data from a table using an api. The following are my code in the controller, route api.php and also in postman. I expect a data should be displayed in postman but instead it was saying `"message": "The route api/v1/public/jualan/view could not be found."`. I wonder what I did wrong here ?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use App\Services\BilService;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class JualanController extends Controller
{
    public function pembelian(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = $request['user_id'];

        $query = DB::table('sales')
            ->where('user_id', $user_id)
            ->get();

        return response()->json($query);
    }
```

and the following are my route in api.php,

```php
Route::prefix('v1/public')->name('api.public.')->group(function () {
    .......
    Route::post('jualan/view', [JualanController::class, 'pembelian']);
        .......
    });
});
```

URL in postman: `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/public/jualan/view`

In postman, I use `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth clearing your route cache

```
php artisan route:cache

php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score -1):

First check the routes of your project in Laravel, use the terminal and execute the command:

```
php artisan route:list
```

check that the route you are trying to access is correctly written.